# Grouping of items in ListView WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, uwp, grouping, collectionviewsource

I have a ListView where I want to group the items based on a field of the item object. Below is the code I have:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyVM.CollectionOfClassA, Mode=OneWay}"
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding DateTimePropertyOfClassA}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Is there something I am missing? I want to group the items based on the DateTime property of ClassA objects. Also, if there is no item for any particular day, I would still like to show that date with empty list under that group (for that day). How can I achieve it?

Edit: I am not able to use CollectionViewSource since my VM contains the collection of ClassA object (which is bound as item source to the listview) and I want to group the items based on one property of those ClassA objects. I am sure there is something I am missing out on. But I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution for anyone looking for it (thanks to the WPF masters out there https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/812ed260-e113-4a8b-9322-226ed56ac90c/grouping-of-items-in-listview-wpf?forum=wpdevelop&prof=required):

```
public class ClassA
{
    public DateTime DateTimePropertyOfClassA { get; set; }
}

public class MyVM
{
    public MyVM()
    {
        //return a grouped collection:
        Grouped = from x in CollectionOfClassA group x by x.DateTimePropertyOfClassA into grp orderby grp.Key select grp;
    }

    public IList<ClassA> CollectionOfClassA { get; set; } = new List<ClassA>()
    {
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-01-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-01")},
            new ClassA(){ DateTimePropertyOfClassA =DateTime.Parse("2016-06-01")}
    };

    public IEnumerable<object> Grouped { get; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs"
                              IsSourceGrouped="True"
                              Source="{x:Bind MyVM.Grouped, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: `IsSourceGrouped` is only available in UWP XAML, it is not present in WPF. This question is tagged with `WPF` - are you actually using UWP instead?

Answer (score -2):

I suggest creating a collection in the ViewModel `IObservableCollection<ClassA>` Properties (or whatever name), add it in the MainWindow class and then simply bind it in the ListView.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Properties}">
```